# How to show Web App Libraries in Package Explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem showing Web App Libraries view in Package Explorer in Eclipse. I believe I have the proper steps to show it by Adding Web App Library in Libraries tab on Java Build Path View. Is there a proper way to add it? Thanks!

Comment: For the sake of argument, is there a WEB-INF folder in the project for it to use, and the necessary files set up so that it knows where that is?

Comment: Yes there is a WEB-INF folder. Yes again, everything is properly set up.

Comment: It does require that it actually be a Dynamic Web Project, having the right natuve, configuration files, and facets set up.